# check mount point usage using ansible

Tags: linux, shell, ansible, ansible-facts

I am trying to list the mount point that are used more than 50% using ansible. I am getting error on AWK.

If I run this command individually it works

```
df -P | awk '$5 >=90 {print}'
Filesystem     1024-blocks     Used Available Capacity Mounted on
tmpfs              2097152  1948868    148284      93% /tmp
```

or

```
df -P | grep /tmp | awk '$5 >=90 {print}'
tmpfs              2097152  1948832    148320      93% /tmp
```

If I put the same command in ansible shell it fails

Here:

```
ansible all -i <hostname>, -m shell -a "df -P | grep /tmp | awk '$5 >=90 {print}'"
SSH password:
SUDO password[defaults to SSH password]:
<hostname> | FAILED | rc=1 >>
awk:  >=90 {print}
awk:  ^ syntax error
grep: write error: Broken pipe
```

Is there a way to do this? Is there a better way to do this? may be using the factors?

Comment: `$5` is replaced by your current shell (from where you run ansible), escape it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **Konstantin Suvorov** your answer worked perfectly.

```
ansible all -i <hostname>, -m shell -a "df -P | grep /tmp | awk '\$5 >=50 {print}'"
SSH password:
SUDO password[defaults to SSH password]:
<hostname> | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
/dev/sda8           944808      55484     840496       7% /var/tmp
tmpfs              2097152    1858344     238808      89% /tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

@user3330284: You could remove the use of grep and give a try to following(not tested it though):

```
ansible all -i <hostname>, -m shell -a "df -P  | awk '/\/tmp/{if(\$5 >=50){print}}'"
```